# How to use Fuzzy logic in ROS..?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to deploy fuzzy logic into ROS , Like novel path planning algorithm based on fuzzy logic for autonomous mobile robots.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56722/how-to-use-fuzzy-logic-in-ros..?/) by [Cybertron](https://answers.ros.org/users/3895/cybertron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-03-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-01**:
Could you edit this so it asks some specific question, please?

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-03-01**:
You either program it or find someone who has... I haven't seen anything around, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I use http://code.google.com/p/fuzzylite/ for my own project where I need to implement a fuzzy controller for collision avoidance. This library is fairly easy to use and only relies on STL, so it's also easy to install. See main.cpp in the src folder for a simple example on how it works. It's not specifically for ROS though, but ROS supports the use of third party libraries. Just link the library to your executable using target_link_libraries in the CMakelists of your project. As far as I know, there is no ROS package dedicated to fuzzy logic.

---

Originally posted by [Hououin Kyouma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1579/hououin-kyouma/) with karma: 205 on 2013-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6